# Get start and end date on right click of selected cell in ExtJS 6.2

Tags: extjs, extjs6.2

I am using Scheduler. 
In grid scheduler when i right click on cell , I want start date and end date of this particular cell.
Code snipped:

```
 listeners: {

        cellcontextmenu: function (view, td, colIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e) 
           {

                e.preventDefault();
                Ext.Msg.alert('Text', 
                record.get(view.ownerCt.columns[colIndex].dataIndex));
      }
}
```

`cellcontextmenu` is calling when I right click on cell...but I am not getting start date and end date..

Comment: @F0XS No he can't, because as far as I know one cannot upload the Bryntum scheduler into Sencha fiddle.

Comment: It's possible to add any code to a Fiddle, here's one with Scheduler: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21u3

Answer (score 2):

Before you try to use ExtJS functions or events on the Bryntum scheduler, please search the Bryntum Scheduler documentation whether a special Scheduler function or event is available.

For instance, on the schedulerpanel there's an event [`schedulecontextmenu`](https://www.bryntum.com/docs/scheduling/5.x/?#!/api/Sch.panel.SchedulerGrid-event-schedulecontextmenu) available that provides the clicked date out of the box.

Comment: you mean to say, should i use schedulecontextmenu instead of cellcontextmenu.

Comment: @debanjanmal Yes, but I also want to provide a general rule so you don't have to return with similar questions in the future. ("If you give a man a fish, you feed him for a day, if you teach a man to fish, you feed him for a lifetime.")

Comment: Thank u for ur advise. I know i am very new in extjs. Before telling, did you check it.It is not working .@Alexander don't fly on the sky...

Comment: I did not explicitly test it with our current 5.1.10, I tested it back in 4.2.7, and yes, `schedulecontextmenu` works. Just for you another test. Code: https://i.imgur.com/aLaP4IF.png
 Result: https://i.imgur.com/chg73aQ.png

Comment: let suppose it works ...then how can i get end date ...
syntax: schedulecontextmenu( scheduler, clickedDate, rowIndex, resource, e, eOpts )

Comment: The whole scheduler is one big cell. When you click somewhere, you get the time that is shown in the tooltip, which may vary from the "cell's" "start" and "end" time. There is no such "cell". If you need the end time with regard to a certain header, you have to get the header alignment from the time axis.

Comment: Try this in our code: `timeAxis = Ext.first('schedulerpanel').timeAxis; var tick = timeAxis.getTickFromDate(new Date(2017, 0, 24)); console.log(timeAxis.getAt(tick).get('start'))`

Comment: schedulecontextmenu does not get fire when i make right click on already existing jobs in scheduler....in empty cell it is working fine

Comment: As I said: you may want to search the Bryntum documentation for suitable events. Search for `contextmenu` gives 21 results, and you may have found [`eventcontextmenu`](https://www.bryntum.com/docs/scheduling/5.x/?#!/api/Sch.mixin.SchedulerView-event-eventcontextmenu)...